# How to draw this diagram using TikZ package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

Please can someone show me how to draw the diagram (photo) using Ti*k*Z package.

[image]

I just arrived to the following diagram

[image]

by using the following code

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\smartqed  % flush right qed marks, e.g. at end of proof
%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, graphicx, hyperref, etoolbox, algorithm, tikz, algpseudocode, algorithm, algorithmicx, tabu, longtable, mathtools, qtree, xcolor, framed, lipsum, caption}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning,shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc, intersections}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
    \ifmmode%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
    \else
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
    \fi}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
    roundnode/.style={circle, draw=green!60, fill=green!5, very thick, minimum size=7mm},
    squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=black!60, fill=red!5, very thick, minimum size=5mm},
    ]
    %Nodes
    \node[squarednode]      (maintopic)                              {BM};
    \node[squarednode]      (uppersquare)       [above=of maintopic] {MC};
    \node[squarednode]      (rightsquare)       [right=of maintopic] {FM};
    \node[squarednode]      (lowersquare)       [above=of rightsquare] {TM};

    %Lines
    \draw[->] (uppersquare.south) -- (maintopic.north);
    \draw[->] (maintopic.east) -- (rightsquare.west);
    \draw[->] (rightsquare.north) -- (lowersquare.south);
    \draw[->] (uppersquare.east) -- (lowersquare.west);
    %\draw[->] (rightsquare.south) .. controls +(down:7mm) and +(right:7mm) .. (lowercircle.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @downvoters: The OP uploaded an MWE 8 hours ago. What is the reason of the downvotes then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

a bit shorter code, exploiting TikZ libraries `arrows.meta` and `quotes`:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,    % <---
                positioning,
                quotes}         % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
     node distance = 12mm and 24mm,
squarednode/.style = {draw=black!60,
                      very thick,
                      align=center,
                      minimum width=15mm,
                      minimum height=7mm,
                      font=\itshape},
       every edge/.style = {draw, -Triangle},       % <---
every edge quotes/.style = {auto=right,
                            font=\small\sffamily}   % <---
                        ]
% nodes
\begin{scope}[every node/.style = {squarednode}]    % <---
    \node   (n11)                   {MC};
    \node   (n12) [right=of n11]    {TM};
    \node   (n21) [below=of n11]    {BM};
    \node   (n22) [below=of n12]    {FM};
\end{scope}
% conection
    \draw   (n11) edge                  (n12)       % <---
            (n11) edge["Algorithm 1"]   (n21)
            (n21) edge["Algorithm 2"]   (n22)
            (n22) edge["Algorithm 3"]   (n12);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can add labels to path by using `node[midway]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, graphicx, hyperref, etoolbox, algorithm, tikz, algpseudocode, algorithm, algorithmicx, tabu, longtable, mathtools, qtree, xcolor, framed, lipsum, caption}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning,shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc, intersections}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
    \ifmmode%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
    \else
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
    \fi}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
    roundnode/.style={circle, draw=green!60, fill=green!5, very thick, minimum size=7mm},
    squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=black!60, fill=red!5, very thick, minimum size=5mm},
    node distance=2cm
    ]
    %Nodes
    \node[squarednode]      (maintopic)                              {BM};
    \node[squarednode]      (uppersquare)       [above=of maintopic] {MC};
    \node[squarednode]      (rightsquare)       [right=of maintopic] {FM};
    \node[squarednode]      (lowersquare)       [above=of rightsquare] {TM};

    %Lines
    \draw[->] (uppersquare.south) -- (maintopic.north) node[midway,left] {Algorithm 1};
    \draw[->] (maintopic.east) -- (rightsquare.west) node[midway,above] {Algorithm 2};
    \draw[->] (rightsquare.north) -- (lowersquare.south) node[midway,right] {Algorithm 3};
    \draw[->] (uppersquare.east) -- (lowersquare.west);
    %\draw[->] (rightsquare.south) .. controls +(down:7mm) and +(right:7mm) .. (lowercircle.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Use some `rotate`s to make your diagram even nicer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, graphicx, hyperref, etoolbox, algorithm, tikz, algpseudocode, algorithm, algorithmicx, tabu, longtable, mathtools, qtree, xcolor, framed, lipsum, caption}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,matrix,positioning,shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc, intersections}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[2]{\relax
    \ifmmode%
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {$#2$};
    \else
    \tikz[remember picture,baseline=(#1.base),inner sep=0pt] \node (#1) {#2};%
    \fi}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
    roundnode/.style={circle, draw=green!60, fill=green!5, very thick, minimum size=7mm},
    squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=black!60, fill=red!5, very thick, minimum size=5mm},
    node distance=2cm
    ]
    %Nodes
    \node[squarednode]      (maintopic)                              {BM};
    \node[squarednode]      (uppersquare)       [above=of maintopic] {MC};
    \node[squarednode]      (rightsquare)       [right=of maintopic] {FM};
    \node[squarednode]      (lowersquare)       [above=of rightsquare] {TM};

    %Lines
    \draw[->] (uppersquare.south) -- (maintopic.north) node[midway,above,rotate=90] {Algorithm 1};
    \draw[->] (maintopic.east) -- (rightsquare.west) node[midway,above] {Algorithm 2};
    \draw[->] (rightsquare.north) -- (lowersquare.south) node[midway,above,rotate=-90] {Algorithm 3};
    \draw[->] (uppersquare.east) -- (lowersquare.west);
    %\draw[->] (rightsquare.south) .. controls +(down:7mm) and +(right:7mm) .. (lowercircle.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could replace manual rotates with `sloped` ;)

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to clean up your packages and your `tikz` libraries. You load `graphicx` thrice and `hyperref` twice. Loading only what you need for your document will speed up your compiling time. Loading packages only once will lead to less errors in complex preambles.

As for an MWE, use a common document class that will reproduce your problem, say `article`. The only package you need to load in your example is `tikz`, as it loads `xcolor` and other packages by default (you can't know that). The only `tikz` library you need is `positioning`, as arrows is used for other kinds of arrows as the ones you used. Look up the libraries in the `tikz` documentation on [CTAN](https://ctan.org).

I eliminated some of the superfluous content in your tikz code (you might want to leave it in if it is necessary for something else, but try without and see if it breaks things) and added text centering and text width in your boxes. Generally, stuff you don't need, toss it out of your code and keep it clean. This will minimize mistakes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        squarednode/.style={%
            rectangle,
            draw=black!60,
            fill=white,
            very thick,
            minimum size=5mm,
            text centered,
            text width=1.5cm,
        }
    ]
    %Nodes
    \node[squarednode]      (maintopic)                              {BM};
    \node[squarednode]      (uppersquare)       [above=of maintopic] {MC};
    \node[squarednode]      (rightsquare)       [right=2.5cm of maintopic] {FM};
    \node[squarednode]      (lowersquare)       [above=of rightsquare] {TM};

    %Lines
    \draw[->] (uppersquare.south) -- node[anchor=east] {Algorithm 1} (maintopic.north);
    \draw[->] (maintopic.east) -- node[anchor=south] {Algorithm 2} (rightsquare.west);
    \draw[->] (rightsquare.north) -- node[anchor=west] {Algorithm 3} (lowersquare.south);
    \draw[->] (uppersquare.east) -- (lowersquare.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The whole thing can be made much shorter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{squarednode/.style={rectangle, draw=black!60,  very thick,
minimum size=5mm},commutative diagrams/arrows={thick,-latex}}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2.3cm,row sep=1.2cm,>=latex]
 |[squarednode]| MC \ar[r] \ar[d,swap,"\textsf{Algorithm 1}"] & |[squarednode]| TM\\
 |[squarednode]| BM \ar[r,swap,"\textsf{Algorithm 2}"] & |[squarednode]| FM 
 \ar[u,swap,"\textsf{Algorithm 2}"]\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]